# Hera 5.1.3 Doesn't shut down or reboot

Tags: release-hera, wingpanel, shutdown

A couple Days ago my fresh eOS install stopped reacting at all when pressing power-off or reboot.

Shutting down works when not logged in or being logged into the guest account.
I cannot figure out why that is, I suppose it has something to do with the removal of xscreensaver but im not sure.

Can someone please assist me in that case?

What I already did:

- editing grub to `acpi=force`
- changing the poweroff delay force from 90seconds to 6 seconds

None of that helped.

I have suspected installs:

- timeshift for backups
- kde-connect
- additional taskbar that shows minimized programs
- wingpanel-indicator-ayatana
- xscreensaver (removed)
- caffeine (removed)

How do I log the shutdown sequence? That would help a lot.

Ordering `shutdown -h` in terminal works but that is no long-time option.

---

EDIT:
`sudo wingpanel` after the problem occurred, reenables the shutdown option. Locking results in Error message:

> (wingpanel:4084): wingpanel-WARNING **: 15:20:26.624: SessionManager.vala:60: Error registering client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
>
> (wingpanel:4084): wingpanel-WARNING **: 15:20:26.624: Wingpanel.vala:53: Failed to register with Session manager
>
> ** (wingpanel:4084): WARNING **: 15:20:56.026: Indicator.vala:163: Unable to lock: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: \n The name org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver was not provided by any .service files
>
> ** (wingpanel:4084): CRITICAL **: 15:20:40.286: DisplayWidget.vala:159: Unknown network state, cannot show the good icon: NETWORK_STATE_FAILED_WIRED
>
> ** (wingpanel:4084): CRITICAL **: 15:20:54.846: session_widgets_userbox_update_state: assertion 'self != NULL' failed

---

EDIT2:

reinstalling wingpanel from pantheon updated the error messages:

When trying to Suspend or Shutdown:

`Unable to shutdown: GDBus.Error:System.Error.ESTALE: Stale file handle`
`Indicator.vala:151: Unable to suspend: GDBus.Error:System.Error.ESTALE: Stale file handle`

i just opened a bug report at github:
https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/issues/320

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. sudo wingpanel fixes this for the moment.
I always put the pc into standby and most of the time, there are two user sessions. 
I just did some tests and could reproduce and "fix" it:

- start E OS
- login with user A
- at the power Menu choose user B
- login with user B
- at the power Menu choose user A
- login with User A
- at the power Menu try to choose User B (you can't choose it anymore)
- at the power Menu, choose standby
  Nothing happens an in the journal, there comes the stale file handle message
- logout user A
- at the login screen, standby or reboot also will not work
- enter Password for logged in User B
- at the power menu, choose standby
  PC will go into standby

this is a very strange behaviour and i also don't have an idea, whats happening.